# Strapi Get Request not returning list of products

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

So I am using Postman for a GET request for my Strapi project.

This is my GET request:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/categories
```

According to Strapi documentation, I should see a list of all the categories.
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#endpoints

However I am just receiving this: [image: Strapi get problem]

Sorry if it seems like a noob question, but I can't find online what I am doing wrong. If anyone knows how to fix this problem it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It could be that you simply forgot to publish your categories if you have enabled draft & publish.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the option "Draft & publish" that

Allows writing a draft version of an entry, before it is published

[image: Configure Advanced settings]

[image: Drafted Image]

Check the option if you want to change that, you could also just published your drafted entries, there is a button to click when you select an item.